# java.sql.Time getTime does not return good value

Tags: java, time, timezone

In my program I need to read a Time value from the database and then convert that value to milliseconds.
I do it like this :

```
Time t = getTimeFromDatabase();
long millis = t.getTime();
```

The problem is that the value of `millis` corresponds to time value which is 1 hour earlier than what is entered in the database.

For example: let's say that the value in the DB is 09:30:00. So if I do this:

```
Time t = getTimeFromDatabase();    
System.out.println(t.toString);
System.out.println(t.getTime);
```

Output would be:

```
09:30:00
30600000
```

Now... 09:30:00 is ok. That's how it is in the DB.

But `30600000 / 3600000 = 8.5` (3600000 is milliseconds per hour). Which means that this value in milliseconds corresponds to 08:30:00.

The correct value for 09:30:00 should be 34200000.

My question is how can I get correct value regardless of time zone (I am in UTC +1, so I guess that this has something to do with my problem).

I have tried with other time values but it is always the same (1 hour earlier).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the DB is not 9:30 at all. In the DB is number of milliseconds and the 9:30 you see is just formatted value. The said formatting is based on timezone, there will be one in the DB and possibly one on the client connection used to show you the data.

Comment: I re-read your question. The point is that for your TZ the correct value for 09:30:00 is 30600000. Use the UTC as TZ if that is your point.

Comment: What database? What is data type of column, *exactly*?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Time`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). This will also eliminate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you parse the data from DB into a Time object, you should use a formatter, and set the proper time zone.

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = timeFormat.parse(dataFromDB); // dataFromDB is a "09:30:10" like String
System.out.println(timeFormat.format(date));  // will print time in HH:mm:ss format
System.out.println(date.getTime()); // will print milliseconds
```